# Why does it print individual letters with += and print the full objects with .append()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does it print individual letters with `+=` and print the full objects with `.append()`?

```
a = ['hello', 'goodbye']
b =[]
for i in a:
  b += i
print(b)
>>['h','e','l','l','o','g','o','o','d','b','y','e']

a = ['hello', 'goodbye']
b =[]
for i in a:
  b.append(i)
  print(b)
>> ['hello','goodbye']
```

I already tried to analyze it print by print but don't get it.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour]( https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Off-site links are not acceptable.  Most of all, repeat your educational materials on the two operations.  You get different results because the two are *supposed* to provide different results.

Comment: Dont paste images of code just paste the code itself. Its easier for us to copy paste also.

Comment: Please revert your edit.

Comment: Either `b.append(i)` or initializing `b = ''` instead of `b = []` will solve the issue.

Comment: Please don’t post code as images. You already had it properly as text, don’t change it. It is, after all, text and we are not going to write it ourselves if we could just copy it from yours.

Comment: Why you edit the post and put an image from your code? the previous post was better. please read how-to-ask and tour as @Prune said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because `+=` work like `extend` method not like `append` method. It means `+=` add a list and when you try to add a `str` to that that make `str` a list of characters and add it to `b` list.

For what you want to do you should use `append` but if you want to use `+=` you can do it this way too.

```py
b += [i]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
b += i
```

This calls the `list.extend` method. It expects an iterable as the argument. So it treats `i` as an iterable. `i` happens to be `'hello'` or `'goodbye'` - these are strings. When you try to treat strings as iterables, they yield the characters in the string. So you end up with each character in the string being added individually to the list.

```
b.append(i)
```

This calls the `list.append` method, which expects only a single element. It merely adds that one element to the end of the list. So you get the complete strings `'hello'` or `'goodbye'` added to the list

Read the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: so += , and .extend() will go through each object through a list, and treat said object as something special, meaning it will take apart the special object and add it to a list.......While .append() will go through each object in a list and simply add it to another list? like what happened in my code?

Comment: Only extend goes treats its argument like an iterable. So it takes the argument apart and adds each piece to the list. While append simply adds its argument to the list as-is

Answer (score 2):

`b += i` is equivalent to `b.extend(i)` where `b` and `i` both are supposed to be iterable objects.

However, in your code you are trying to extend a list with a string object (elements of `a`). Here, python implicitly converts string to list in order to extend it to `a`. String to list conversion results in a list in which every character of the string is an individual element.

Whereas `append` means simply adding the element to the list in its original object form. Therefore, the string 'hello' gets appended to `b` as a new element.

Comment: `i` is not a list

Comment: I know. I meant the intention of the extend expects it to be a list or iterable.